# Why does my keras LSTM model get stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am trying to build a small LSTM that can learn to write code (even if it's garbage code) by training it on existing Python code. I have concatenated a few thousand lines of code together in one file across several hundred files, with each file ending in `<eos>` to signify "end of sequence".

As an example, my training file looks like:

```
setup(name='Keras',
...
      ],
      packages=find_packages())
<eos>
import pyux
...
with open('api.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(sign, f)
<eos>
```

I am creating tokens from the words with:

```
file = open(self.textfile, 'r')
filecontents = file.read()
file.close()
filecontents = filecontents.replace("\n\n", "\n")
filecontents = filecontents.replace('\n', ' \n ')
filecontents = filecontents.replace('    ', ' \t ')

text_in_words = [w for w in filecontents.split(' ') if w != '']

self._words = set(text_in_words)
    STEP = 1
    self._codelines = []
    self._next_words = []
    for i in range(0, len(text_in_words) - self.seq_length, STEP):
        self._codelines.append(text_in_words[i: i + self.seq_length])
        self._next_words.append(text_in_words[i + self.seq_length])
```

My `keras` model is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=len(self._words), output_dim=1024))

model.add(Bidirectional(
    LSTM(128), input_shape=(self.seq_length, len(self._words))))

model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(self._words)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But no matter how much I train it, the model never seems to generate `<eos>` or even `\n`. I think it might be because my LSTM size is `128` and my `seq_length` is 200, but that doesn't quite make sense? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you converting your words into numerical tokens?  How are you actually feeding in your data to fit your model?  All I see right now is defining the current and next sequence but those are the actual tokens themselves.

Comment: I am one hit encoding the tokens to vectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, when there is no `limit for code generation` or `the <EOS> or <SOS> tokens are not numerical tokens` LSTM never converges. If you could send your outputs or error messages, it would be much easier to debug.

You could create an extra class for getting words and sentences.

```
# tokens for start of sentence(SOS) and end of sentence(EOS)

SOS_token = 0
EOS_token = 1


class Lang:
    '''
    class for word object, storing sentences, words and word counts.
    '''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.word2index = {}
        self.word2count = {}
        self.index2word = {0: "SOS", 1: "EOS"}
        self.n_words = 2  # Count SOS and EOS

    def addSentence(self, sentence):
        for word in sentence.split(' '):
            self.addWord(word)

    def addWord(self, word):
        if word not in self.word2index:
            self.word2index[word] = self.n_words
            self.word2count[word] = 1
            self.index2word[self.n_words] = word
            self.n_words += 1
        else:
            self.word2count[word] += 1
```

Then, while generating text, just adding a `<SOS>` token would do.
You can use https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow , a character level rnn for reference.