# LSTM getting caught up in loop

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch, lstm

I recently implemented a name generating RNN "from scratch" which was doing ok but far from perfect. So I thought about trying my luck with pytorch's LSTM class to see if it makes a difference. Indeed it does and the outpus looks way better for the first 7 ~ 8 characters. But then the networks gets caught in a loop and outputs things like "laulaulaulau" or "rourourourou" (it is supposed the generate french names).

Is it a often occuring problem ? If so do you know a way to fix it ? I'm concern about the fact the network doesn't produce EOS tokens...
This is an issue which has already been asked here [Why does my keras LSTM model get stuck in an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211215/why-does-my-keras-lstm-model-get-stuck-in-an-infinite-loop)
but not really answered hence my post.

here is the model :

```
class pytorchLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size):
        super(pytorchLSTM,self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(hidden_size,input_size)
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim = 2)

    def forward(self, input, hidden)
            out, hidden = self.lstm(input,hidden)
            out = self.tanh(out)
            out = self.output_layer(out)
            out = self.softmax(out)
        return out, hidden
```

The input and target are two sequences of one-hot encoded vectors respectively with a start of sequence and end of sequence vector at the start and the end. They represent the characters inside of a name taken from the name list (database). 
I use a  and  token on each name from the database. here are the function I use

```
def inputTensor(line):
#tensor starts with <start of sequence> token.
    tensor = torch.zeros(len(line)+1, 1, n_letters)
    tensor[0][0][n_letters - 2] = 1
    for li in range(len(line)):
        letter = line[li]
        tensor[li+1][0][all_letters.find(letter)] = 1
    return tensor

# LongTensor of second letter to end (EOS) for target
def targetTensor(line):
    letter_indexes = [all_letters.find(line[li]) for li in range(len(line))]
    letter_indexes.append(n_letters - 1) # EOS
    return torch.LongTensor(letter_indexes)
```

training loop :

```
def train_lstm(model):
    start = time.time()
    criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
    n_iters = 20000
    print_every = 1000
    plot_every = 500
    all_losses = []
    total_loss = 0
    for iter in range(1,n_iters+1):
        line = randomChoice(category_line)
        input_line_tensor = inputTensor(line)
        target_line_tensor = targetTensor(line).unsqueeze(-1)
        optimizer.zero_grad()       
        loss = 0
        output, hidden = model(input_line_tensor)
        for i in range(input_line_tensor.size(0)):
            l = criterion(output[i], target_line_tensor[i])
            loss += l
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

the sampling function :

```
def sample():
    max_length = 20
    input = torch.zeros(1,1,n_letters)
    input[0][0][n_letters - 2] = 1
    output_name = ""
    hidden = (torch.zeros(2,1,lstm.hidden_size),torch.zeros(2,1,lstm.hidden_size)) 

    for i in range(max_length):
        output, hidden = lstm(input)
        output = output[-1][:][:]
        l = torch.multinomial(torch.exp(output[0]),num_samples = 1).item()
        if l == n_letters - 1:
            break
        else:
            letter = all_letters[l]
            output_name += letter
        input = inputTensor(letter)
    return output_name
```

The typical sampled output looks something like that :

```
Laurayeerauerararauo
Leayealouododauodouo
Courouauurourourodau
```

Do you know how I can improve that ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your `sample` function. What is it supposed to do? Create a name? Could you give some example outputs from it? And where is it used, in your training loop/when creating dataset/other configuration?

Comment: The ```sample``` function feeds in the one-hot encoded "start of sequence" token to the network and asks for the output, which is a probability distribution from which the next letter is drawn. Then this letter is fed to the network and you repeat this process until "End of sequence" token is generated. It is used when the network has been trained, to generate names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the explanation :

When using instances of the `LSTM` class as part of a RNN, the default input dimensions are `(seq_length,batch_dim,input_size)`. To be able to interpret the output of the lstm as a probability (over the set of inputs) I needed to pass it to a `Linear` layer before the `Softmax` call, which is where the problem happens : `Linear` instances expects the input to be in the format `(batch_dim,seq_length,input_size)`.

To fix this, one needs to pass `batch_first = True` as an argument to the `LSTM` upon creation, and then feed the RNN with an input of the form `(batch_dim, seq_length, input_size)`.

Comment: I'm glad this helped in your case but its just correcting wrong configuration, it doesn't address the problem

Answer (score 2):

Some tips to improve the network in the order of importance (and ease of implementing):

### 1. Training data

If you want your generated samples to look real, you have to give some real data to the network. Find a set of names, split those into letters and transform into indices. This step alone would give way more realistic names.

### 2. Separate start and end tokens.

I would go with `<SON>` (Start Of Name) and `<EON>` (End Of Name). In this configuration neural network can learn combinations of letters leading to `<EON>` and combinations of letters coming after `<SON>`. ATM it's trying to fit two different concepts into this one custom token.

### 3. Unsupervised Pretaining

You may want to give your letters some semantic meaning instead of one-hot encoded vectors, check [word2vec](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec) for basic approach.

Basically, each letter would be represented by `N`-dimensional vector (say 50 dimensions) and would be closer in space if the letter occurs more often next to another letter (`a` closer to `k` than `x`).

Simple way to implement that would be taking some text dataset and trying to predict next letter at each timestep. Each letter would be represented by random vector at the beginning, through backpropagation letter representations would be updated to reflect their similarity.

Check [pytorch embedding tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.html) for more info.

### 4. Different architecture

You may want to check Andrej Karpathy's idea for generating baby names. It is simply described [here](https://ndres.me/post/using-neural-network-generate-startup-name).

Essentially, after training, you feed your model with random letters (say 10) and tell it to predict the next letter.

You remove last letter from random seed and put the predicted one in it's place. Iterate until `<EON>` is outputted.

Comment: Tip 1 and 2 are already part of my implementation (honnestly I didn't thought It would be that hard to generate names ! I'm starting to fear for what I actually wnat to achieve with RNNs...) I will look into tip 3 and 4 thanks !